# How to store and retrieve tabledata using userdefault Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

My task is user `data` appending into `items` array with `strut` method and assigning to `tableView` tableData `array`. In my code multiple places I used tableData for some `validations`.

Now, my problem is I can able to see my table data when I move `background` to `foreground` but If I remove application from `background` then again If I am open my `application`, There is `empty` tableView. So, I need to understand. how tableData `store` into `UserDeafult` and then `retrieve` to load tableView for avoid `data` loss.

```
// Array declaration
var items = [Item]()
var tableData = [Item]() 

public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController,didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

    // Here I am getting user selected file url and its name from iCloud.
    // I skipped to paste here.

    // User picked file data appending into items array
    items.append(Item(url: bookurl, title: name))

    // Assign items data to tableData
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:"items") {
        do {
            let itemsUser = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<Item>.self, from: data)
                tableData = itemsUser
        } catch { print(error) }
    }
}  

// MARK - TABLE VIEW DELEGATIONS
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return self.tableData.count
}

// TableView data-load 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let item = tableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.name_label.text = item.name
    }
   return cell
}
```

Comment: Where are you doing the fetch from userdefaults?

Comment: We need to see more code to tell where you are facing the issue. Please share more of your code. Preferably thw whole class if it isn't too big.

Comment: Please check I updated my code in post @RakeshaShastri

Comment: You should have the logic for getting the tableData from user defaults outside that delegate preferably in a method which you would call whenever you need the table populated with that data. And of course call `reloadData()` after that.

Comment: I am sorry I can't able to understand. You mean I need to maintain this **if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:"items") {...}** outside of the picker document delegation? @RakeshaShastri

Comment: yes, because as far as i can see it is needed more than at that one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For above scenario `UserDefault` should be `outside` of the `picker delegation`. If we maintain within `viewDidload` with some `logic` then It will work well.

```
//Within ViewDidLoad
 if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:"items") {
        do {
            let itemsUser = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<Item>.self, from: data)
                tableData = itemsUser
        } catch { print(error) }
    }
```